# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on frida

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, frida

I am trying to hook function of android messaging application.
I run frida hook script. then I get a following error:

`Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "i0.a.a.a.e3.z" on path: DexPathList[[/data/app/xxxxx==/base.apk]]`

In Jadx-Gui, base.apk is decompiled as follows

```
package i0.a.a.a.e3;
    /* loaded from: classes5.dex */
    public final class z {
    }
```

script is as follows

```
let z = Java.use("i0.a.a.a.e3.z");
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: In Jad-GUI there should be a comment right above the class with the info in which dex file the class is located in, please update your post and include this comment. Also please also include the relevant parts of your frida script that throws the ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: Please add some more details.

Comment: I have added to the question.
I find the package name "i0.a.a.a.e3.z" strange
Is it possible to check if it is included in the apk?

Comment: are you sure the decompiled apk is the same installed one?

Comment: do you launch frida with -U argument?

Comment: I pulled apk from installed device.

Answer (score 1):

Try running your hook inside the `Java.perform()` method of Frida.

```
Java.perform(function() {
    let z = Java.use("i0.a.a.a.e3.z");
    z["somefunction"].implementation = function (str) {
        console.log('somefunctionis called' + ', ' + 'str: ' + str);
        let ret = this.somefunction(str);
        console.log('somefunctionret value is ' + ret);
        return ret;
    };
})
```

It solved my problem that was similar to yours.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: I suggest you iterate over the loaded classes and find the correct path to your class: https://codeshare.frida.re/@BenGardiner/android-list-loaded-classes/

Comment: I couldn't find the target class.
Does that mean the class is not used in this app?

Comment: No, I believe it's there, we just need to find it :) note: if it's an internal class then the path is as follows - `let z = Java.use("i0.a.a.a.e3$z");`. Notice the $ sign for internal classes.